# How can I expect PowerLine Networking to work?

Tags: powerline-networking

I think I read before that it depends on the powerline in your house, so can I expect it to work at least ok at my home?

Do I need to sync it all the time (eg. when I switch off the power)? Or does it automatically detect the other side ?

What kind of speeds/stability can I expect? Better than wireless?

What other things must I need to know ?

Comment: No need to "sync" all time, the Adapters search and find each other automatically, they only need to be configured to the same password (which is the default condition).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not knowing the state of the wiring in your house makes this a bit difficult to answer except for some general points:

- You can get powerline units that have headline speeds of 14 (pretty much old tech now), 85, 200Mbit/sec and 1Gbit/sec and they are generally backwards compatible with each other
- You plug them in and they 'just work', provided the mains wiring's not horrendously bad
- The units work on a single phase and within the domestic metered zone but will not necessarily behave between phases (many housing areas are wired with each house on a separate phase to balance the load on the local transformer)
- The units may struggle to work at best speed if you plug them into power extensions - especially if the extensions have any form of surge or spike protection.
- Most makes of unit can have a 'secret' group/ID set on them so that someone can't come along with their own plug and join your network
- If you want to stream HD video across a powerline link, go for 200Mbit units or better
- I have streamed standard definition video across 85Mbit plugs with no apparent problems
- I have used the units with VoIP telephones and gaming consoles with no noticeable lag or performance issues
- I have two 85Mbit units in my house (built around 1870 and rewired in the 1970s) between floors and the effective speed according to the tools that came with them say I am getting a speed of around 67Mbit/sec - so a bit better than to 54Mbit wireless.

Invite me round for tea and I'll bring a couple to try - or see if you can borrow a couple from a friend.